# Problems with the guestbook demo. SQL connectivity issues PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to get familiar with the APP Engine so I'm going through a few tutorials. 
But when trying to get the guestbook to work, I've installed the App engine TDL , python 2.7 MySQL database and workbench. All that works fine. I did the first part hello world and everything works fine.

But when I try to put the guestbook to work I get errors when I try to connect to either the local db or the cloud SQL with the code given to me.

The tutorial is here.

## guestbook.html

```
26     $db = new pdo('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/even-advantage-xxx;even-advantage-xxx:guestbook;dbname=guestbook','root', '');

36     $db = new pdo('mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;dbname=guestbook', 'root', 'googtest');
```

This is the error I get on the web site

> Guestbook Entries {"outcome":false,"message":"Unable to
>   connect.","0":{"errorInfo":null}}

The link I provided is a cut and paste except for the changes to line 26 and 36 to
reflect the proper instance names.

Comment: Can you link this tutorial? Can't help you without more info on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you sure your local mysql has a database named guestbook with user root and password googtest?

Comment: Is the MySQL server even running? How did you test this? Firewall in the way?

Comment: local database is active and tables for tutorial are up as well as sample data put into it.I've double checked the password.

Comment: Thats odd the link I posted didn't show up .            https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#PHP_Connecting_to_your_Cloud_SQL_instance

Comment: I turned off the firewall and avast was disabled, still the same problem.

Comment: Here is the log file from my developer console. 67.71.32.xxx - - [04/Apr/2014:16:51:30 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 156 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0" "even-advantage-xxx.appspot.com" ms=97 cpu_ms=82 cpm_usd=0.000017 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117c3f16ba6affc0e7bcba354793b16967 app_engine_release=1.9.2
    W 19:51:30.566

PHP Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in /base/data/home/apps/s~even-advantage-xxx/1.374911844383622803/guestbook.php on line 26
    W 19:51:30.568

Comment: part 2 of the log.PHP Warning: PDO::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=-1 in /base/data/home/apps/s~even-advantage-xxx/1.374911844383622803/guestbook.php on line 26
    I 19:51:30.570

Comment: OK I just modified the error printout to be a little more precise.This is on localhost side.{"outcome":false,"message":"Unable to connectSQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.\r\n"}

Comment: This is the Cloud side error. Unable to connect.SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that the database status from the developer console is runable and not running .

Comment: Got the local part working as even though I configured it all properly via workbench, the server service was set to manual.I still am having trouble with the CLoud part though. Same error.Unable to connect.SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solutions. Be sure the MySQL service is started on your developer server. I thought all was fine because I could create tables and such via the workbench but didn't realaise the server was set to manually start.

As for the Cloud SQL errors, it was the way the sample code was written and the way the developer console shows the info. I was taking the instance to be even-advantage-xxx and the instance name to be even-advantage-xxx:guestbook but in reality the instance name is only the guestbook part.  even-advantage-xxx:guestbook together is regarded as the instance ID. They could have prevented the confusion if they just said 'enter inscanceID here!'

But at least its all working now. Put this in for others if needed.

Pete